# Meaning of the word ''pads" here

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> **public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength)**: Copies the specified array and length. It truncates the array if provided length is smaller and **pads** if provided.

This sentence is from the field of programming - arrays. What does **pads** mean in this context? Which other word could there be used with the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a computer programming term.

If the source length is greater than the target size, it is truncated. That means any extra characters are ignored.

If the source length is shorter than the target size, the target is typically **padded** with spaces to the required length.

This means that **space** characters are inserted to fill the target to the required length.

An alternative word for **pad** could be **fill**.

For a numerical value the padding could be with **zeroes**.